# jquery Tablesorter - How to apply sortAppend to a specific column

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Is it possible to trigger a sortAppend to a specific column?   Ie - if a user sorts on column 4, then I want the secondary sort to occur on column 2; otherwise I want the secondary sort to be on column 1..

I tried:

```
    $(element).tablesorter({
    headers: {
        3: {sortAppend:[[1,0]]}
    }
```

If I always want to append, it does work correctly..

```
$(element).tablesorter({
    sortAppend:[[1,0]]
    }
```

??

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not an ideal solution, but it works. This code does not work with the original version of tablesorter*, but it will work with my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).

Try this code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/3264/)):

```
$(function () {
    $('table')
        .tablesorter({
            theme: 'blue',
            widgets: ['zebra', 'columns']
        })
        .on('sortBegin', function(evt, table){
            var c = table.config,
                list = c.sortList;
            // only modify sort if one column was chosen
            if (list.length === 1) {
                // if sorting column 3, add column 2
                // any other column, add column 1 (zero-based indexes)
                list.push( (list[0] && list[0][0] !== 3) ? [1, 0] : [2, 0] );
            }
        });
});
```

* the reason it won't work with the original tablesorter is that the original doesn't have a `sortBegin` event which occurs after the `sortList` has processed. If you try to use the `sortStart` event, it clears the `config.sortList` so any changes that you make are lost.